# PowerBI: Add Average Total at the end in Matrix Visual

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I have data like this to display in a Matrix Visual. How do I add an Average total at the end that averages the data from the previous weeks of the current month?

Thanks

Add Average Total to Matrix Visual
[image]